# How would I find the area under the curve of $y = \frac{x^{2}+7}{3x-x^{2}}$ from x = 1 to 2?

Tags: definite-integrals, area

I am told to find the area under the curve of $y = \frac{x^{2}+7}{3x-x^{2}}$ from x = 1 to x = 2.

Using long division, the integrand simplifies to $[-1+\frac{3x+7}{3x-x^{2}}]$.

But then how do I proceed from here? Trig substitution?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of that.

Comment: So I solved it twice, and I continue to get the wrong answer. I have 23ln(2)/3...not sure what I did wrong. Edit: ah, forgot the 1!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the partial fractions method

Comment: This answer would be more appropriate as a comment in my opinion. If you would like to leave it as a hint, consider adding more information e.g. a suggestion as to how to simplify the function in order to do the integration.